# How to automatically select value from drop down list in asp.net core mvc using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

The method here is not working.

Here is my cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="inputState">City</label>
  <select id="City" class="form-control basic" asp-for="City" 
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities," Id","ZoneName"))"
    readonly="@(Model.IsView ? true : false)">
    <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#CustomerName").change(function () {
  var CustomerName = $("#CustomerName").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "../Ticket/FetchCustomerAddress",
    data: { userId: CustomerName },
    type: "Get",
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data.city);
      //debugger;
      $('#City').val(data.city);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      //console.error(err)
      //alert("Internal server error.");
    }
  })
});
```

I am populating the list with the cities. I want to automatically select the city in the list getting from `data.city`

Comment: Hi @Sharad Kulshrestha. can you please share your model design? Besides, i saw you use `alert(data.city);,`  does it alert the correct value? Also if possible please share your `FetchCustomerAddress` return data.

Answer (score 2):

ASP generate new Id's for your inputs in client side ,

So you select html would look like

```
<select ID="City" class="form-control basic" asp-for="City" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities,"Id","ZoneName"))" readonly="@(Model.IsView ? true : false)">
     <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
</select>
```

the generated id for this is : `City.ClientID` ,
so in order to access this selected , you js code should look like

```
...
success: function (data) {
                        
  alert(data.city);
  //debugger;
  $("#<%=City.ClientID%>").val(data.city);

},
...
```

note the `$("#<%=City.ClientID%>")` `-->` is new generated id would be printed in selector

Comment: How to get this clientid in the jquery form?

Comment: already posted in the answer , try what I've posted ! `$("#<%=City.ClientID%>")`

Comment: Its Not Working

Comment: have you changed the select as mentiend capitalized ID , `<select ID="City"`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 $("#City option[value=data.city]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#City').val(data.city);` is the correct way to set selected value for dropdownlist.

For this constructor: `new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities,"Id","ZoneName"))`,  the first parameter is the source, the second parameter is each option **value** in select, the third parameter is that each option displays **text** in html.

That is to say, `Id` represents the option value and `ZoneName` represents the option text.

When you set the value for select, you need be sure the `data.city` value equals to any value of `Id`.

Testing code:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model Test
<select id="CustomerName">
    <option>custom1</option>
    <option>custom2</option>
    <option>custom3</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">City</label>
    <select id="City" class="form-control basic" asp-for="City"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities,"Id","ZoneName"))">
        <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#CustomerName").change(function () {
        var CustomerName = $("#CustomerName").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/FetchCustomerAddress",
            data: { userId: CustomerName  },
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.city);    
                $('#City').val(data.city);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //console.error(err)
                //alert("Internal server error.");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Cities = new List<City>()
    {
        new City(){Id=1,ZoneName="aa"},
        new City(){Id=2,ZoneName="bb"},
        new City(){Id=3,ZoneName="cc"}
    };
    return View();
}

public IActionResult FetchCustomerAddress(string userId)
{
    //do your stuff...
    return Json(new Test() { City = "2" });
}
```

Render view:

[image]

Ajax response data(press `F12` in browser -> click `Network` panel -> choose `FetchCustomerAddress` method name -> choose `Response`)

[image]